# Mock location not working on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, mocking, location

I have used code from [this](http://www.cowlumbus.nl/forum/MockGpsProvider.zip). I have changed it a bit. Below is my code snippet. The problem is Google Map is not showing proper location which i have mocked.

```
public class MockGpsProviderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
public static final String LOG_TAG = "MockGpsProviderActivity";
private static final String MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX = "GpsMockProviderIndex";

private MockGpsProvider mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
private Integer mMockGpsProviderIndex = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Use saved instance state if necessary. */
    if (savedInstanceState instanceof Bundle) {
        /** Let's find out where we were. */
        mMockGpsProviderIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX, 0);
    }

    /** Setup GPS. */
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    // // use real GPS provider if enabled on the device
    // locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    // }
    // else if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
    // otherwise enable the mock GPS provider
    locationManager.addTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_LOW,
            Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, true);
    locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // }

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        /** Load mock GPS data from file and create mock GPS provider. */
        try {
            // create a list of Strings that can dynamically grow
            List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            /**
             * read a CSV file containing WGS84 coordinates from the 'assets' folder (The website http://www.gpsies.com offers downloadable
             * tracks. Select a track and download it as a CSV file. Then add it to your assets folder.)
             */
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("mock_gps_data.csv");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            // add each line in the file to the list
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(line);
            }

            // convert to a simple array so we can pass it to the AsyncTask
            String[] coordinates = new String[data.size()];
            data.toArray(coordinates);

            // create new AsyncTask and pass the list of GPS coordinates
            mMockGpsProviderTask = new MockGpsProvider();
            mMockGpsProviderTask.execute(coordinates);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // stop the mock GPS provider by calling the 'cancel(true)' method
    try {
        mMockGpsProviderTask.cancel(true);
        mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    // remove it from the location manager
    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // store where we are before closing the app, so we can skip to the location right away when restarting
    savedInstanceState.putInt(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX, mMockGpsProviderIndex);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // show the received location in the view
    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    view.setText("index:" + mMockGpsProviderIndex + "\nlongitude:" + location.getLongitude() + "\nlatitude:" + location.getLatitude()
            + "\naltitude:" + location.getAltitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/** Define a mock GPS provider as an asynchronous task of this Activity. */
private class MockGpsProvider extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "GpsMockProvider";
    public static final String GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    /** Keeps track of the currently processed coordinate. */
    public Integer index = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {
        // process data
        for (String str : data) {
            // skip data if needed (see the Activity's savedInstanceState functionality)
            if (index < mMockGpsProviderIndex) {
                index++;
                continue;
            }

            // let UI Thread know which coordinate we are processing
            publishProgress(index);

            // retrieve data from the current line of text
            Double latitude = null;
            Double longitude = null;
            Double altitude = null;
            try {
                String[] parts = str.split(",");
                latitude = Double.valueOf(parts[0]);
                longitude = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);
                altitude = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                break;
            } // no data available
            catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            } // empty or invalid line

            // translate to actual GPS location
            Location location = new Location(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
            location.setLatitude(latitude);
            location.setLongitude(longitude);
            location.setAltitude(altitude);
            location.setAccuracy(1);
            location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            location.setBearing(0F);
            location.setSpeed(0.0F);   

            // show debug message in log
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

            // provide the new location
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, location);

            // sleep for a while before providing next location
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);

                // gracefully handle Thread interruption (important!)
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                    throw new InterruptedException("");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }

            // keep track of processed locations
            index++;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onProgressUpdate():" + values[0]);
        mMockGpsProviderIndex = values[0];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What location is it showing? Is it your actual location or something seemingly random? And are you running it on a physical device or on the emulator?

Comment: It is showing random location on that path. I am running on device.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
location.setAccuracy(16F);
location.setAltitude(0D);
location.setBearing(0F);
```

Comment: My research at one point of time showed that mocking location on real device is sporadic..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call mock location also in your permissions (Manifest.xml), in order to work. Do you have that,in your permissions?

Because when I used it with  [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/),it worked.

(Sorry I couldn't leave it as a comment because I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on Allow_Mock_Location in the setting of your physical device? It's under developer options.

Answer (score 0):

Also add for your mock location
location.setSpeed(5);
speed more than 1, like 5 or 10